# In a Chrome Extension, can a Service Worker receive Native Messaging with no browser window open?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-native-messaging

We have been shipping a Chrome extension since the beginning, year 2011 or whatever.  The extension works with our macOS native bookmarks management app, giving it access to Chrome bookmarks via Native Messaging.  Our native app can read and write Chrome bookmarks, and is notified whenever bookmarks are changed in Chrome, thanks to `chrome.bookmarks.xXXXXXX.addListener`.

For pushing bookmarks changes into Chrome, our extension is expected to respond to messages from the native app, *even when there is no browser window open in Chrome*.  (Chrome always opens a browser window upon launch, but the user may close it.)  I'm pretty sure this worked in older versions of Chrome, and it still works in Edge, Firefox, and Opera.  But in recent versions of Chrome, our extension does not respond to Native Messages *unless there is at least one browser window open.*  I suspect this behavior is collateral damage from the depracation of background scripts in favor of Service Workers.

Our extension has a manifest V2 and a `background.page`.  I understand that we must migrate to manifest V3 and am working through that.  I understand how to migrate our `background.page` to a `background.script`, eliminating the `background.html` page.  The next step would be to migrate the Background Script into a Service Worker.  I have read [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages/) explaining how Listeners must be installed synchronously.

But I'm wondering, will this work in the end?  Do Service Workers support responding to events like Native Messaging when no browser windows are open?

Probably our requirement is relatively rare.  Thank you.

Comment: There's no essential difference: the service worker is just a non-persistent background script without a bunch of stuff like DOM. What you need is the same: adding `background` to `permissions` in manifest.json and enabling "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" option in the browser settings (it's enabled by default).

Comment: Thank you, @wOxxOm. I've researched that setting "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed", and I think it is mis-named, or maybe it makes sense on devices other than a Mac.  In Mac terminology, I think it means "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is *not running*" or, even more Mac-speak "is quit".  In any case, it is not the issue I'm describing.  Our extension is not expected to work when Chrome is not running.  But it is expected to work when Chrome is running with no browser window open.  Such a state is not possible in most OSs, but it is on a Mac.

Comment: In that case it's a bug and you can report it in https://crbug.com.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking it may be a bug and shall file.  But I shall update my extension to manifest V3, and migrate the old background script to a Service Worker before filing, so my bug report will be taken more seriously.

Comment: Technically you can create a DevTools window for the extension and keep it open indefinitely, in minimized mode. If you launch the DevTools window of the `ServiceWorker` when the browser window is open, even after the main browser window is closed the DevTools window can/will remain open and receiving/sending messages. You can also keep a subprocess running after the browser closes. I had no modify a WASM example because `wasmtime` does not terminate when all windows, incl. DevTools, close https://github.com/guest271314/native-messaging-webassembly/blob/main/nm_c_wat.sh.